# How to restrict user to select only one child from parent node Kendo Tree view MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-treeview

I want allow the user to select only one child from the parent node, means

consider a treeview

P1

- C1
- C2
- C3

P2

- A1
- A2
- A3

P3

- S1
- S2
- S3

Here user can select multiple childe node but the restriction is that the user can only select one child in one parent node

I found a fiddle link for it which can disable selection once you select one child but it disables all node, and im unable to disable those checkboxes up to its parent only.

[here is the link](http://jsfiddle.net/csnsgiri/y1rntc28/)

I changed that javascript with

```
            $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                checkboxes: {
                    checkChildren: true,
                  template:"# if(!item.hasChildren){# <input type='checkbox'  name='checkedFiles[#= item.id #]' value='true' />#}#"
                },

        dataSource: [
          { id: 1, text: "My Documents", expanded: true, spriteCssClass: "rootfolder", items: [
            { id: 2, text: "Kendo UI Project", expanded: true, spriteCssClass: "folder", items: [
              { id: 3, text: "about.html", spriteCssClass: "html" },
              { id: 4, text: "index.html", spriteCssClass: "html" },
              { id: 5, text: "logo.png", spriteCssClass: "image" }
            ]
            },
            { id: 6, text: "New Website", expanded: true, spriteCssClass: "folder", items: [
              { id: 7, text: "mockup.jpg", spriteCssClass: "image" },
              { id: 8, text: "Research.pdf", spriteCssClass: "pdf" },
            ] }
          ] },
          { id: 9, text: "Reports", expanded: true, spriteCssClass: "folder", items: [
              { id: 10, text: "February.pdf", spriteCssClass: "pdf" },
              { id: 11, text: "March.pdf", spriteCssClass: "pdf" },
              { id: 12, text: "April.pdf", spriteCssClass: "pdf" }
            ] }
          ]
            });
  
  
  $('#treeview').on('click', 'input:checkbox', function(){
    var checkboxes = $('#treeview input:checkbox');
    var selected = checkboxes.filter(':checked');
    checkboxes.not(selected).prop('disabled', selected.length > 0)
})
```

I tried with trying to find its closest('ul').find('li input') then restrict disable only that ul but it did not work as im not good in jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using the check event. Triggered after the user has checked or unchecked a checkbox. If checkChildren is true, the event is triggered after all checked states are updated. This event has been introduced in internal builds after 2014.2.828.

```
<div id="treeview"></div>
<script>
    $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
        checkboxes: true,
        dataSource: [
          { text: "foo", items: [
              { text: "bar" }
          ] }
     ],
     check: function(e) {
         console.log("Checking", e.node);
         var checkboxes = $(e.node).parent().find("input:checkbox");
         var selected = checkboxes.filter(':checked');
         checkboxes.not(selected).prop('disabled', selected.length > 0);
     }
});
</script>
```

you can see the details [here](https://dojo.telerik.com/epIJEpUC)

Comment: thanks for the help dojo's demo is exactly what I want, definitely, I'll check it.. first need to verify if my kendo DLL's are up versions or not..

Comment: did you try? @T.Giri